# Is it possible to use BlockBlobService in Azure Functions (python)?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I am creating an Azure function (python) that reads pickle file from Azure Blob Storage. I am using **BlockBlobService** for this purpose and its working fine in **Spyder**. However, when i tried to implement same approach in Azure function, its not working. What could be the reasons for this issue? Is it so because **BlockBlobService** is not available in Azure functions (python preview)? What could be the alternatives to it?

Comment: which error are you facing?

Comment: How long does it take to process the block blob? Can you be more specific about what you are doing in AF?

Comment: why would it be not available, depending on the error you might need to install the appropriate python package or fix something else

Comment: @IvanYang  I am publishing the azure functions to Function App and invoking URL to see the result. I am not getting any result.

Comment: @kgalic It actually takes few seconds to process the block blob. I am storing a pickle  file in Blob and trying to read it as pickle file with python script in Azure Function.

Comment: So reading file fails? Have you tried to run the same Python code, outside of AF and see if it works?

Comment: @4c74356b41 I am importing it as 'from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService'

Comment: @kgalic I tried outside AF and it works fine.

Comment: well, did you install the appropriate package?

Comment: did you verify that Python version in AF and your local for testing is the same? Maybe some packages are missing as someone mentioned before. Can you share some logs? Would you be open to using something else except AF?

Comment: @4c74356b41 I have installed Azure Storage extension for VS Code. Do i need to add some other packages as well?

Comment: @kgalic Actually, I don't have any logs to share. I need to use AF but i am open to use something else , for instance, urllib3, for this purpose. My only requirement is azure function (python) loads the pickle file stored in Azure Blob Storage.

Answer (score 1):

Did you include a 'requirements.txt' file? You can run this code in the directory before deploying to Azure:

`pip freeze >> requirements.txt`

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason is that you're missing the azure blob storage package.

You can try creating a virtual environment locally, then install all the packages and publish.

Here is a [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-function-python#bash-or-a-terminal-window) on creating virtual environment for app functions.

Comment: I have installed Azure Storage extension for VS Code. Do i need to install some other packages?